# Chrome extension how to force page show mobile view

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I use following code in crx background.js, but not enongh, google.com to mobile view but instagram.com still desktop

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function (details) {
    for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
      if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'User-Agent') {
        details.requestHeaders[i].value = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Mobile Safari/537.36";
        break;
      }
    }
    return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
  },
  {urls: ['<all_urls>']},
  ['blocking', 'requestHeaders']
);
```

I find chrome devtools > "toggle device" can force instagram show mobile view, so how to do same thing in chrome extension?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution:

**in short**

Not only change http request header "User-agent", **but also change js "navigator.userAgent"**

**Detail**

I use "Save All Resources" download all instagram js to local: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-all-resources/abpdnfjocnmdomablahdcfnoggeeiedb?hl=en

and I use intellij idea search "mobile" and "isMobile" **function**(idea > navigate > symbol"

I find instagram is not used http request "User-Agent", it use js navigator.userAgent get userAgent

**So I should change navigator.userAgent in crx content script** and set content script **document_start** in crx manifest.json

following is content script, **remember set content script "run_at" "document_start" in manifest.json**

```
var actualCode =  '(' + function() {
    'use strict';
    var navigator = window.navigator;
    var modifiedNavigator;
    if ('userAgent' in Navigator.prototype) {
        // Chrome 43+ moved all properties from navigator to the prototype,
        // so we have to modify the prototype instead of navigator.
        modifiedNavigator = Navigator.prototype;
    } else {
        // Chrome 42- defined the property on navigator.
        modifiedNavigator = Object.create(navigator);
        Object.defineProperty(window, 'navigator', {
            value: modifiedNavigator,
            configurable: false,
            enumerable: false,
            writable: false
        });
    }
    // Pretend to be Windows XP
    Object.defineProperties(modifiedNavigator, {
        userAgent: {
            value: "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Mobile Safari/537.36",
            configurable: false,
            enumerable: true,
            writable: false
        },
        appVersion: {
            value: "5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Mobile Safari/537.36",
            configurable: false,
            enumerable: true,
            writable: false
        },
        platform: {
            value: "Linux x86_64",
            configurable: false,
            enumerable: true,
            writable: false
        },
    });
} + ')();';
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.textContent = actualCode;
document.documentElement.appendChild(s);
s.remove();
```

above code how to get mobile view "userAgent", "appVersion", "platform"? chrome devtools > toggle device, when page is in mobile view, in devtools console, `navigate.userAgent`, `navigate.appVersion`, `navigate.platform`

update:
I find following code is important:

```
 var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.textContent = actualCode;
    document.documentElement.appendChild(s);
    s.remove();
```

If use `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"` and change navigator.userAgent, userAgent cannot be changed